# Simple geometry/analysis question

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Sure, I can intuitively see that $\tan x \geq x$ for all $x \in(0,\frac{\pi}2)$. But how to more carefully prove this (without using power series)? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\tan x-x$. Then $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)=\sec^2 x-1$. Note that the derivative is positive for $0\lt x\lt \frac{\pi}{2}$, since $\sec^2 x$ is defined and $\gt 1$ in this interval.

So $f(x)$ is increasing in the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. It follows that $\tan x\gt x$ in the interval $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

**Remark:** For a "calculus-free" (geometric) proof, the pictures you drew are sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Andre. Can you think of a method without calculus? This problem occurs in the proof that the limit of $\frac{\sin x}x$ is 1.

Comment: Oh okay, I got it now: just compare the areas of the shaded sector and shaded triangle.

Comment: For that, your picture is very good, and enough. The alternative way to find the derivative of $\sin x$ is to define it using a power series, skipping the geometry. But if we will use the geometry to define $\sin x$, then you are stuck with geometric proofs of the relevant inequalities.

Comment: Personally, I like the pictures. Purists might complain that they show only a single value of the angle $x$. For those folks, you need a movie rather than a static picture :-)